# How to exploit XSS in Angular with $sceProvider being disabled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, security, web

I am trying to implement XSS vulnerable app so that afterwards I could improve security aspects by using Domain Driven Design principles. The front-end is implemented with AngularJS for which I have disabled $sceProvider. Still, any of the XSS attack examples I tried so far didn't work.

**HTML page:**

```
<div class="row" ng-init="loadArticles()">
    <h1>Existing articles</h1>
    <table id="tabela1"  class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book title: </th>
            <th>Description: </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="b in BOOKS track by $index" >
            <td style="padding-right: 15px">{{b.title.value}}</td>
            <td style="padding-right: 15px">{{b.description.value}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

**ArticleController.js**

```
$scope.loadArticles = function () {
    console.log("loading articles");

    var url = "/api/article/getAll";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'text',
        success:  function (data) {
            $scope.BOOKS = JSON.parse(data);
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //toaster poruka
            alert('Could not load articles!');
        }
    });
};
```

When for example

```
<script>alert();</script>
```

is put into description, and sent to server to be saved into database, next time the page is loaded, it is printed in the same way, without the alert being shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont get it with {{}} or ng-bind, you can get it with ng-bind-html or similar things.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

angular.module('plunker').config(function ($sceProvider) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.x ='<img src="wrongUrl" onerror="alert(1)"/>';
});

<div ng-bind-html="x"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for fast response, that did solve it ! Can you just tell or tell me where to look for explanation of why it doesn't work with {{}} or ng-bind ?

Comment: In angular source you can see that ng-bind uses elem.textContent = smth, which is native js and wont allow any html, scripts.